# Heatmap on a sphere

Tags: matlab, plot, heatmap

I have done a project where i am cooling a metal sphere. Now i want to model the temperature on the surface of the sphere in Matlab. I have the fourierseries u(r,t) which i want to plot at r=1. How do i plot this? So far i have

```
R=1
t=0;
N=1000;
T0=-10;
T1=10;
a=1.3*(10^-7);
u=T0;

[x,y,z]= meshgrid(0:.1:R, 0:.1:R, 0:.1:R);
S= sqrt(x.^2+ y.^2 + z.^2);
r=1
for k= 1:1:N;

    La_k= (k.*(pi)/R).^2;
    r_k=(r.^(-1)).*sin(sqrt(La_k).*r);
    u= u+ ((T1-T0)^2) *  ((-1)^(k+1))  *  (R/(k*(pi)))  *  exp(-a.*La_k.*t)        
end
surf(x,y,u)
colorbar
colormap(jet)
```

Comment: What are the values of `R` and `N`?

Comment: R is the radius of the metal sphere, so in this case R=1.

Comment: N is how terms i include from the Fourier series.

Comment: It seems like you want to plot `u(r=1, t)` but you did not record the history as it evolves. Also, `x,y,z` are not used in `u`, is it because it only depends on radius magnitude?

Comment: yes i want to plot u(r=1,t). Yes temperature depends only on r and t

Comment: how does `t` change in every loop iteration? like `dt`?

Comment: There's two good ways: 1.change t manually, like let t=0,1,.. 2. Let u be a function of t and the let the plot change over time, in this case i would define a dt.

Answer (score 0):

You may record the evolution of `u` along the time. 
Since the temperature is only dependent on radius, for each time frame, you will have to convert the single temperature value to a matrix that's acceptable by `surf`, ie the `CData` which has the same size as `x,y,z`.

```
r=1;
t=0;
N=1000;
T0=-10;
T1=10;
a=1.3e-7;

% evaluate u(r,t) at each time step, and record
[x,y,z]= sphere(100);
u = zeros(N,1);
u(1) = T0;
for k = 2:N
    La_k= (k*pi/r)^2;
    r_k=(r^-1).*sin(sqrt(La_k)*r);
    u(k) = u(k-1)+ (T1-T0)^2 * (-1)^(k+1) * r_k/(k*pi) * exp(-a*La_k*t);
end
% create dummy plot
hs = surf(x,y,z,nan(size(z)));
colorbar
colormap(jet)
title(' ')
% fix color scale so you can see color change along with time
hs.Parent.CLim = [min(u),max(u)];
% iterate over time and show temperature with color
for kk = 1:N
    hs.CData = ones(size(z))*u(kk);
    title(sprintf('t = %d', kk))
    drawnow
    pause(0.01)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. in u(k) u forgot to include r_k.

Comment: @hola just did.

Comment: If i want longer time, i increase N, but why won't the colorbar change with it?

Comment: it just goes from -10 to -9.9999999

Comment: @hola Well two issues here. First I think the system tends to stabilize. You would probably see less and less change in temperature as time goes on. Second, `t` does not change in the loop. You may consider using `dt`, but the exact implementation really depends on the physical question you have.

Comment: Do a hand calculation on the problem and give a guessimation first. Otherwise i don't know if computer is telling the truth.

Comment: Why is u a vector, with elements differing by k. it should just be a vector depending on t

Comment: I know. Right now u is only a function of k so that k is chaning in the plot and not t.